# Adjusting label according to its data in ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom UITableViewCell design as

[image]

What I want to is that "points" label should come under the last digit in my Numbers label. Lets say I have 1990 value in my Numbers label the "points" labels should come uder the last digit "0" in this case.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want that Points either starts from the last digit or finishes at the last digit?

Comment: I wanted them to start from last digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Horizontal Space between the `points` label and the `number` label with a negative value roughly equates the width of 1 character

For instance here:
[image]

Here in this example the horizontal space is `-30` while the font size of the `number` label is 61pt. You can see that it is roughly one character width. (Of course you can apply more complicated math if you please to get the exact value you desire or accommodates your design principle)

And with making sure that the `number label` does not have an explicit `width` constrain it will automatically expand to fit its contents and therefore pushing the `points` label appropriately. 
like this:

[image]